# Powershell encode JSON array in URL for RestMethod

Tags: powershell, rest, api

I am using Knack to solve a business process issue, however to ensure it's success I need to run a daily script to sync the data between Knack and our HR system.

Knack uses a REST API and I want to apply a filter to the GET call so that I don't have to populate a local table in order to compare the data.

Knack requires a JSON array like the example below to be encoded in the URL in order to filter the results returned.  The example shows how to do this in Javascript but I cannot work out how to do this in Powershell would anyone be able to assist?

```
 // Request route
var api_url = 'https://api.knack.com/v1/objects/object_1/records';

// Prepare filters
var filters = {
  'match': 'or',
  'rules': [
             {
               'field':'field_1',
               'operator':'is',
               'value':'Dodgit'
             },
             {
               'field':'field_1',
               'operator':'is blank'
             }
           ]
};

// Add filters to route
api_url += '?filters=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(filters));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
$api_url = 'https://api.knack.com/v1/objects/object_1/records'
$filters = @'
{
  'match': 'or',
  'rules': [
             {
               'field':'field_1',
               'operator':'is',
               'value':'Dodgit'
             },
             {
               'field':'field_1',
               'operator':'is blank'
             }
           ]
}
'@
$CompressedFilters = $filters | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 -Compress
$encodedUri = "{0}?filters={1}" -f $api_url,[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($CompressedFilters)
```

**Explanation:**

`$filters` is defined as a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7). `$filters` is piped into [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7) and then to [ConvertTo-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7) in order to compress the JSON data easily. However, that does swap single quotes for double quotes.

[UrlEncode()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode?view=netframework-4.8) from the `System.Web.HttpUtility` .NET class encodes special characters in URLs.

`-f` is the string format operator. This helps to build your URI string. The final URI is stored in `$encodedUri`.

**NOTE:** The `[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode` encodes special characters with lowercase hex characters. If your system requires uppercase hex characters, then use `[System.Net.WebUtility]::UrlEncode` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much this is perfect for what I needed!  Worked straight away!